# Is a Data-filled SQL table queryable while setting up a new index?

Tags: sql, database, indexing

Given a live table in SQL with some non-trivial number of columns/entries, with one or more applications actively querying it, what would be the effect of introducing a new index on some column of this table? **What takes priority? Serving the query, or constructing the index?** Put another way, would setting up the index be experienced by the querying applications as a delay in getting their responses?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the database while indexing is taking place, but it's effects on performance is nearly impossible for us to say. A great deal about the optimizer is magic to anyone who hasn't worked on it themselves, and the answer could change greatly depending on which RDMS you're using. On top of that, your own hardware will play a huge part in the answer.

That being said, if you're primarily reading from the table, there's a good chance you won't see a major performance hit, if your system has the IO/CPU capabilities of handling both tasks at the same time. Inserting however, will be slowed down considerably.

Whether this impact is problematic will depend on your current system load, size of your tables, and what exactly it is you're indexing. Generally speaking, if you have a decent server, a lowish load, and a table with only a few million rows or less, I wouldn't expect to see a performance hit at all.